Laravel Yajra Datatable Search on relations / orWhereHas
i have a problem with my yajra datatable script, where the search function not working perfectly for some column (column is from relation table, not the main table), here
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = JobTraining::with('workplace:id,name')
        ->select('id', 'letter_number', 'created_at', 'status', 'workplace_id')
        ->where('created_by', auth()->user()->id);

    if ($request->has('search') && $request->search['value'] != '') {
        $search = $request->search['value'];
        $query->where(function($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('letter_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
              ->orWhere('status', 'like', "%{$search}%")
              ->orWhereHas('workplace', function($q) use ($search) {
                  $q->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
              });
        });
    }

    $data = $query->get();

    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);
}

search function working perfectly for letter_number, status, created_at, but not for wokrplace.name. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Try join instead of with

What do you mean by 'not working perfectly'? Also, can you write out (and test) the SQL you want the $query to generate?
